# Storing properties of a custom component in session scope or bean

Tags: xpages

I've written a new back-end Java component (extending UIComponentBase) as an alternative for the ExtLib Application Layout control. The control needs to show a collection of data that is looked up from another Notes application. The data is user dependant and doesn't change from page to page so, to avoid repeatedly doing a lookup to the other application, I want to store it in the session scope.  (Note that because this is a layout control, there will only ever be one per page.)

I know I could use a session-scoped maanged bean (and have done in previous iterations) but the data only needs to be used in this control and shouldn't be used elsewhere on the page which it could be with a bean. So my question is, what's the best practice approach I should take here? Should I just directly store the data in the sessionMap or am I missing a trick with the component stateHolder? Or am I stuck with using a bean?

Thanks

(Edited for clarification)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant or not, but NotesIn9 #143 which is about to be published has a demo of binding to a component itself rather then the values. So possibly there's some relevant information in there.  I really don't know.

Comment: Look into managed beans. Check out PerHenricks example. http://per.lausten.dk/blog/2012/02/creating-your-first-managed-bean-for-xpages.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, Simon :-)

Comment: You SHOULD store it in component's local datasource (compositeData or custom datasource), instead of session scope. Two instances of your component at the same page may interfere with unexpected results (unless you use component specific key of sessionScope).

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I've updated my question with some clarification as I'm developing a back-end Java component, not a custom control within the NSF. 

Frantisek, that's a very good point. The component itself is a layout control component so it should only ever appear once on a page by design but I probably should build in some error checking to be sure.

David - I look forward to that demo!

Comment: You could extend *com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataComponentBase* instead. It would allow you to use your own *dataContext* variables for your component.

Comment: After reading your question over and over again, I still don't unterstand your problem: Why don't you want to use a bean? A session-scoped bean is *exactly* build for this purpose: To store user-specific data and to share them between different pages. When storing data in the *sessionMap*, you do exactly the same when using a session-scoped bean, because the bean is stored in the *sessionMap* too. And adding data "directly" to the *sessionMap* allows the access on other pages too. Please explain....

Comment: Pedantry. Using a bean and having to declare it in faces-config.xml felt like the wrong approach. As I eventually discovered last night, what I was trying to achieve was implementing something in the same way as `com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.layout.ConversationState`
Yes, it gets stored directly in the _sessionMap_ and technically it's available to any control on any page but it feels like the right approach for what I'm trying to achieve, especially as it turns out there isn't a session version of the component StateHolder.

Comment: To be pedantic too: You don't need to register a managed bean in the *faces-config.xml*. You can create it easily programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're talking about your own back-end Java components rather than Custom Controls within a single NSF.

I'm not sure at what level, when you write your own native XPages components, the properties are cached by the stateHolder when calling saveState(). I would presume no higher than View, for the reasons Frantisek says, that otherwise it would be unclear which instance to update if you had multiple on one XPage but one on another. It couldn't update both at the same time on the same page, so I would guess that each is a separate instance. As a result, the same component on multiple pages would be a separate discreet instance.

But there's nothing stopping you, in specific setters of the component, writing to sessionScope as well as the private property, and then doing the reverse on the getter. I'm not sure if you'd want to try the internal property before trying sessionScope or vice versa. It would depend how you wanted to handle the situation of the same sessionScope being updated from multiple pages (if the collection could change).

Comment: Thanks Paul. I'm circling around a similar conclusion - that the stateHolder interface caches properties at no higher than View level because the whole point is for component classes to "save their state between requests" (as per Mastering XPages Ed.1 page 462).

Comment: Writing that, I think the solution has become more apparent. I suspect that the stateHolder will save state between requests for the same instance of a component. Because this is a layout control, even though it's a single component, it will be different instances of the component (1 per XPage - or at least 1 on a Custom Control which is on every XPage). I could be mistaken but I'm guessing it's not the stateHolder's purpose to cache properties at that level.

Comment: Accepting Paul's answer because it led me to the eventual solution which was basing my code on `com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.layout.ConversationState` found in the ExtLib which stores the data required for the Application Layout in the _sessionMap_